# Design a simple C++ iterator for Matrix

Tags: c++, c++11

I was thinking to design a simple C++ iterator with `++` operation behave differently for backward and forward iterations like STL. So that a matrix `A` can be access through row and column as below,

```
  A.row(3).begin()
  A.row(3).end()
  A.col(3).begin()
  A.col(3).end()
  A.col(3).rbegin()
  A.col(3).rend()

  ++ A.row(3).begin()
  ++ A.col(3).rbegin()
```

My matrix class would look like below,

```
class Matrix {
 public:
  Iter row(size_t rowID);
  Iter col(size_t colID);
 private:
  vector<int> data_{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
  size_t nRow{3};
  size_t nCol{2};
};
```

Is there any suggestions on how I can design my `Iter` class?

Comment: @Bathsheba lets only focus on row iterator now, is there any better way to design ++ for forward and backward iteration?

Comment: The iterators for iterating over rows would need to behave differently than iterators that iterate over columns.   A way to keep things simple would be for those iterators to have distinct types.   If they are the same type, there is nothing stopping a user of your class using iterators that work with rows with iterators that work with columns in ways that don't make sense.

Comment: For your first snipped to work, methods `row` and `col` should not return iterators but iterable objects (objects that have functions `begin` and `end`). Only these methods should  return iterators, which should be different for rows and columns like @Peter said. Well, you probable would have to implement only column iterator. A normal pointer would be sufficient for rows.

Comment: I think you should watch Stepanov lectures: https://www.youtube.com/user/A9Videos/playlists

Comment: I'd advise to use different classes for row and col iterators - for efficiency sake, because one represents contiguous memory while the other isn't. In STL - they use different classes iterator and reverse iterator - similar principle. This way row iterator basically returns a span... while col iterator is more troublesome.

Comment: Shouldn't this be on [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) ?

Comment: @GauravSingh: Absolutely not. Where is the completed code?

Answer (score 3):

Here the C++ solution without boost. I also provide a complete and tested source code example.

The source code is compiled and tested with MS Visual Studio 19.

First hint: I would always use `std::valarray` for matrix calculations. Please read about it.

Explanation to this solution:

We will used a vector of vector of int to represent the matrix.
Rows can be easily accessed. They are the first dimension of the data matrix. If we want a iterator for a row, we simple return the standard iterator for a vector. With that, we will immediately have full functionality. Simple.

Unfortunately columns are different. They are slices in the contiguous memory of the data. So, what we will implement as a solution is: Create a vector for each column with references to the data in the correct position.

That sounds more easy than it is, because we cannot store references in containers in C++. So, either to use `std::reference_wrapper` or build our own reference wrapper. I had issues with assigning values to dereferenced `std::reference_wrapper` and build an own one. A assignment operator has been added.

With that, we can return an iterator to columns, based on the reference vectors.

And, we have the full power of iterators for the matrix class, with minimum effort, by simply reusing the std::vector::iterator capabilities.

I put some test code in main

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <tuple>
#include <sstream>
#include <numeric>


// Unfortunately the std::reference_wrapper does not work as expected.
// So we will build our own one
class IntRef
{
    // Here we will store the reference
    std::tuple<int&> t;
public:
    // Constructor. Take reference and store it in tuple
    IntRef(int&& intV) : t(intV) {}     

    // Assignment to the referenced value
    int operator =(const int i) { std::get<0>(t) = i; return i; }      

    // Explicit type cast to int&
    operator int& () { return std::get<0>(t); }                        

    // And, return the reference
    decltype(&std::get<0>(t)) operator&() { return &std::get<0>(t); }  
};


// Some definitions to make reading easier
using IntRefV = std::vector<IntRef>;
using MatrixCIterator = std::vector<IntRef>::iterator;
using Columns = std::vector<int>;
using MatrixRIterator = Columns::iterator;


// The matrix
class Matrix
{
public:
    // Constructor defines the matrix size
    Matrix(size_t numberOfRows, size_t numberOfColumns);

    // Iterators for rows are simple, becuase we have vectors of columns. Use unterlying iterator
    MatrixRIterator rowIterBegin(size_t row) { return data[row].begin(); }
    MatrixRIterator rowIterEnd(size_t row) { return data[row].end(); }  

    // Column iterator is complicated. Retzurn iterator to vevtor of references to column values
    MatrixCIterator columnIterBegin(size_t column) { return columnReferences[column].begin(); }
    MatrixCIterator columnIterEnd(size_t column) { return columnReferences[column].end(); }

    // Access data of matrix
    std::vector<int>& operator [] (const size_t row) { return data[row]; }

    // And, for debug purposes. Output all data
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Matrix& m) {
        std::for_each(m.data.begin(), m.data.end(), [&os](const Columns& columns) {std::copy(columns.begin(), columns.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(os, " ")); std::cout << '\n'; });
        return os;
    }
protected:
    //The matrix, vector of vector of int
    std::vector<Columns> data; 

    // The references to columns in data
    std::vector<IntRefV> columnReferences{};    
};

// Constructor. Build basic matrix and then store references to columns in data 
Matrix::Matrix(size_t numberOfRows, size_t numberOfColumns) : data(numberOfRows, std::vector<int>(numberOfColumns)), columnReferences(numberOfColumns)
{
    for (size_t column = 0; column < numberOfColumns; ++column) 
        for (size_t row = 0; row < numberOfRows; ++row)
            columnReferences[column].emplace_back(IntRef(std::move(data[row][column]))); // Std::move creates a rvalue reference (needed for constructor, nothing will be moved)
}



// Some test data for the istream_iterator
std::istringstream testData("1 2 10");



// Test the matrix
int main()
{
    // Define a matrix with 3 rows and 4 columns
    Matrix matrix(3, 4);
    // Test 1: Fill all values in column 2 with 42
    for (MatrixCIterator ci = matrix.columnIterBegin(2); ci != matrix.columnIterEnd(2); ++ci) {
        *ci = 42;
    }
    std::cout << matrix << "Column 2 filled with 42\n\n";

    // Test 2: Read input from istream and copy put that in column 1
    std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<int>(testData), 3, matrix.columnIterBegin(1));
    std::cout << matrix << "Column 1 filled with testData '"<< testData.str() << "'\n\n";

    // Test 3: Copy column 2 to cout (Print column 2)
    std::copy(matrix.columnIterBegin(2), matrix.columnIterEnd(2), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << "This is column 2\n\n";

    // Test 4: Sum up the first 2 values of column 1 and show result
    std::cout << "\nSum of first 2 values of column 1:  " << std::accumulate(matrix.columnIterBegin(1), matrix.columnIterBegin(1)+2, 0) << "\n\n";

    // Test 5: Fill all values in row 0 with 33
    std::for_each(matrix.rowIterBegin(0), matrix.rowIterEnd(0), [](int& i) { i = 33; });
    std::cout << matrix << "Row 0 filled with 33\n\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Hope that this gives you an idea on how it could work . . .

Answer (score 2):

You can simply store the "stride" inside the iterator, that is how far the pointer moves each time it is incremented or decremented.  Along one axis the stride is 1, while on the other it is the dimension of the matrix.

If your matrix is this:

```
1 2 3 4
6 7 8 9
```

Then row(0).begin() points to 1 and row(0).end() points to 6 (with stride of 1), while column(2).begin() points to 3 and column(3).end() points to an unused cell below 8 (with stride of 4).

`boost::make_strided_iterator()` will do this for you.