# How to extract columns of a 2D array in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, pointers

My task is to count the no of elements greater than an element a<sub>ij</sub> in the corresponding row `i` and column `j` for every element of a 2D array in C++. My way is to extract the i<sup>th</sup> row and j<sup>th</sup> column, sort them and traverse the sorted array with a  counter variable until a<sub>ij</sub> element is found.

But the problem is in extracting the entire row `i` and entire column `j` for every such element. I know that the row can easily be extracted with `std::copy` function in c++.

```
int **adj=new int *[n];

for(r=0;r<m;r++)
   for(c=0;c<n;c++)
       cin>>adj[r][c];

int buf[n];
std::copy(adj[i], adj[i] + n, buf);
```

But how to extract the corresponding j<sup>th</sup> column?

I can easily do it with a looping structure like:

```
int buf[m];
for(r=0;r<m;r++)
   buf[r]=adj[r][j];
```

but this will increase time complexity keeping in mind that this operation is required for every element of the array. Any better way to do this?

Comment: If your code works, you have no questions regarding specific code-related problems and you wonder how to optimise your solution, CodeReview is the place for you, not StackOverflow.

Comment: @Fureeish I disagree, this is a fine question here, since it's very limited to a specific problem. This has no place on CodeReview.

Comment: @ruohola I disagree that this has no place on CodeReview. OP came up with an algorithm that presumably solves their problem and wonders whether the solution can get any better. This seems like a great fit for CodeReview and borderline offtopic on StackOverflow. One may mention cache friendliness, more efficient algorithms and so on, but this is usually CodeReview's job.

Comment: "My task is to count the no of elements greater than an element aij in the corresponding row i and column j for every element of a 2D array" So you have to create another matrix C, where Cij = count of (...) Aij. Is it correct?

Comment: @Bob__ yes you are right.

Answer (score 4):

If you decide to write program in C++, then

- Stop using plain C-Style arrays. There is No reason whatsoever for C-Style arrays. Do never use them again. Simply stop this.
- Stop using raw pointers. For now and ever. Do not use raw pointers
- Do not use new. Never
- The language C++, which you want to use, does not support VLA (avariable length arrays), Do not use C-Style arrays in the first place and not at all VLA (like `int buf[m];`
- Especially, do not use such constructs, if you do not understand how thew work

In you first row, you are writing

```
int **adj=new int *[n];
```

With that you are allocating an array of pointer. Those pointers are not initialized. They point to somewhere random in the memory.

And with

```
for(r=0;r<m;r++)
   for(c=0;c<n;c++)
       cin>>adj[r][c];
```

You are getting user input and write them into random memory, somehwere, undifined, corrupting the heap and causing a crash.

With

```
int buf[n];
std::copy(adj[i], adj[i] + n, buf);
```

you copy some random values into buf. It will look like it works. But it is only by accident.

In the future please use `std::vector` or `std array` (if you know the dimension at compile time). For 2 dimensional arrays use a vector of vectors.

See the following example:

```
int main()
{
    const size_t numberOfRows = 3;
    const size_t numberOfColumns = 4;

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> a2d(numberOfRows, std::vector<int>(numberOfColumns));

    // Fill a2d with data
    for (size_t row = 0; row < a2d.size(); ++row) {
        for (size_t col = 0; col < a2d.front().size(); ++col) {
            std::cin >> a2d[row][col];
        }
    }

    // Get 2nd row
    std::vector<int> row(numberOfColumns);
    std::copy(a2d[1].begin(), a2d[1].end(), row.begin());

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this valuable answer. It will help me clear my concepts. However can you address this issue ----(Can I extract/Is there any way to extract) columns of this 2D vector without copying elements one by one(as I have shown in the question(but with vectors instead)? . If possible kindly provide a syntax.

Comment: If you want to use columns directly, then you need to use a ````std::valarray```` and slices. Or something as desribed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56816493/design-a-simple-c-iterator-for-matrix/56824094#56824094. Not so easy. Even not in C. Or use one of the many available matrix libraries, for example eigen.

Comment: "For 2 dimensional arrays use a vector of vectors." is very bad for performance.  Also, there is no reason to stop using arrays.  And raw pointers are the correct tool for non-owning access.

Answer (score 1):

> But the problem is in extracting the entire row i and entire column j for every such element.

The algorithm you are trying to implement doesn't need to copy and sort the row and the column every time. You can copy and sort each row and each column once, then reuse those for every element. While time consuming, it should be asintotically faster than traversing the rows and columns multiple times to count the greater values.

See e.g. the following implementation (testable [HERE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/RGpuRiuakxaEuMqu)).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> a {
        {3, 5, 1, 2},
        {8, 0, -2, 7},
        {1, -5, 3, 6},
    };

    // Make a transposed copy. That's really cache unfriendly
    auto a_t = std::vector<std::vector<int>>(a[0].size(), std::vector<int>(a.size()));
    for (size_t r = 0; r < a.size(); ++r)
    {
        for (size_t c = 0; c < a[r].size(); ++c)
        {
            a_t[c][r] = a[r][c];
        }
    }
    // Sort the rows of a_t (columns of a)
    for (auto & row : a_t)
    {
        std::sort(row.begin(), row.end());
    }   

    auto c = std::vector<std::vector<int>>(a.size(), std::vector<int>(a[0].size()));
    for (size_t i = 0; i < c.size(); ++i)
    {
        // Sort a (copied) row at a time.
        auto row_copy(a[i]);
        std::sort(row_copy.begin(), row_copy.end());

        // The columns have already been copied and sorted,
        // now it just takes a couple of binary searches.
        for (size_t j = 0; j < c[i].size(); ++j)
        {
            auto it_r = std::upper_bound(row_copy.cbegin(), row_copy.cend(), a[i][j]);
            auto it_c = std::upper_bound(a_t[j].cbegin(), a_t[j].cend(), a[i][j]);
            c[i][j] = std::distance(it_r, row_copy.cend())
                    + std::distance(it_c, a_t[j].cend());
        }
    }

    for (auto const & row : c)
    {
        for (auto i : row)
            std::cout << std::setw(3) << i;
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: Do note that the matrix needs to be very large for the sort-then-N-searches method to beat the naive method.  The searches can be eliminated by sorting tuples of (value,index) and accessing `c[i][j]` in permuted order.